# Indexing in arrays when using fgets

Tags: c, arrays, indexing, fgets

I'm teaching myself programming. I read that a string stored in an array of characters can be indexed to extract the nth character.

However, I've been trying to solve this for hours: I realized trying to solve an exercise that I can only access the first character of the array `myarray[0];` whereas the rest of index (1,2,3...) values will return nothing. However, if I use the `puts` function it does return the whole string. Curious thing: `strlen` is returning the length of my array +1.

**example:**

```
    int main (void)
    {
    char myarray[1000]={0};
    int i;

    fgets(myarray,1000,stdin);
    for(i=0;i<strlen(myarray);i++)
       printf("myarray[%d]:%c\n",i,myarray[i]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("strlen:%d\n",strlen(myarray));
    puts(myarray);
    return 0;
    }
```

**input:**
6536

**output:**

```
strlen:5
myarray[0]:6
myarray[1]:
myarray[2]:
myarray[3]:
myarray[4]:
6536
```

Comment: It works great for me... 6536
myarray[0]:6
myarray[1]:5
myarray[2]:3
myarray[3]:6
myarray[4]:


strlen:5
6536

Comment: fgets() stores the newline character, which is why you see strlen() returning one more character than you expect.

Comment: Your code and output do not match. Please post the exact code generating the problem and the exact output.

Comment: Weird - works for me too. Are you sure this is the code you're running? Did you `#include <stdio.h>`?

Comment: since the length cannot be negative, better `size_t i`

Comment: Maybe tell us more about the environment you're using, @Kamajii gave the explanation for strlen. What OS are you using? What compiler?

Answer (score 4):

You are getting this result most probably because of undefined behavior of your program. You are using wrong format specifier to print a `size_t` type (`strlen`return `size_t` type). Change the format specifier to `%zu`.

Also note that in `for` loop you need to declare `i` as `size_t` type.
Here is the fixed code: http://ideone.com/0sMadV

Comment: And the comparison between signed and unsigned types should be fixed.

Answer (score 3):

`fgets` writes a newline character `\n` into the buffer to represent newlines in the input stream. Thus `strlen` returns 5.

Answer (score 0):

The actual output is :

```
6536
myarray[0]:6
myarray[1]:5
myarray[2]:3
myarray[3]:6
myarray[4]:


strlen:5
6536
```

As you can see, `myarray[4]` stores the newline (due to `fgets`). Also, it would be better to calculate `strlen` once by placing it above the loop, instead of in every iteration.

From [here](http://char%20*fgets(char%20*restrict%20s,%20int%20n,%20FILE%20*restrict%20stream);):

```
char *fgets(char *restrict s, int n, FILE *restrict stream);
```

> The fgets() function shall read bytes from stream into the array
>   pointed to by s, until n-1 bytes are read, or a  is read and
>   transferred to s, or an end-of-file condition is encountered. The
>   string is then terminated with a null byte.

A simple way is to for `strlen(var)-1`. Another way is to remove the newline with null terminating character:

```
if (myarray[length - 1] == '\n')
    myarray[length - 1] = '\0';
```

where `length = strlen(myarray);`

Answer (score 0):

The strlen counts the '\n' at the end of the string. You can "fix" it with strtok:

```
strtok(myarray, "\n");
```